# How do I access the wp-config.php file using CLI in OpenShift?

Tags: wordpress

I need to edit the `wp-config.php` file that is on our OpenShift instance. What commands should I run in the terminal to open, edit, and save the instance?

Comment: there are a variety of text editors that you can use.  Vim, gedit, atom, etc.

Comment: We can't use a text editor; it has to come through the command line interface since it's hosted in OpenShift (unless for some reason, I am missing it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `oc` cli for that.

```
$ oc login <api-endpoint>
$ oc project <wp-project>
$ oc rsh <pod-name>
$ vi <wp-installation-dir>/wp-config.php
```

Save and exit file. But your configuration should be in a persistent location. Otherwise it will not survive pod restarts.